# Флаг docker в docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Как в docker-compose задаётся флаг `--memory` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `docker-compose` v2 - это `mem_limit` (должно работать из коробки):

```yml
version: "2.1"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    mem_limit: 10m
```

Для `docker-compose` v3 - через `deploy`:

```yml
version: "3.7"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 13m
```

Т.к. `deploy` относится к `Docker Swarm` вы можете увидеть такое сообщение предупреждение (выдает такое на Linux, тогда как на Docker for Mac работает все ок):

> WARNING: Some services (nginx) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.

Но можно сказать `docker-compose` чтобы он попытался конвертировать не поддерживаемые ключи без использования `Swarm`. При помощи такой команды ограничение будет работать: `docker-compose --compatibility up`.